# Serial programming issue after using ISP

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, arduino-uno, atmega, arduino-ide

I've been using the avr-mkII programmer to program the arduino through ISP for the past month. Recently I noticed that ever since doing that I lost the ability to program the arduino through the USB port - Serial 0. Does anyone have a clue as to how to reset the boards back to normal? I tried this with a few different boards and it is all the same. The  New boards that haven't been programmed through the ISP act normally. I basically have lost the ability to communicate with the usb programmer chip. Has anyone experienced this before? Would I need to program the usb communication chip through it's ISP pins? Here the typical generic response that I get when I try to program them.

```
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting the correct board and programmer in the IDE and then choosing the option "Burn Bootloader" will upload the stock bootloader and set the fuses appropriately on the main MCU.

Comment: Awesome. I had no idea that programming via ISP would overwrite the bootloader. As you pointed out, all I had to do was to burn the bootloader again to revert to serial programming. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It *shouldn't* unless the image is very large or the fuses are reprogrammed.